# Custom route doesn't use :id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I've created a custom route in my routes.rb to clone my activities by the activity ID as following:

```
resources :activities
get "/activities/:id/clone" => "activities#clone", :as => :clone_activity
post "/activities/:id/clone" => "activities#clone"
```

When I use `<%= clone_activity_url(@activity) %>` now; It shows me `http://localhost:3000/activities//clone`. instead of the ID attached.

Why isn't my ID showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the routes inside a block like this

```
resources :activities do
  get "clone" => "activities#clone", :as => :clone_activity
  post "clone" => "activities#clone"
end
```

This will make it so that a GET or POST to the path `/activities/:activity_id/clone` will trigger the method at `activities#clone`

Furthermore, the route will be called "activity_clone_activity_path" (or url) - you can change this in your code if you want, also this will only reference the `get` path since you only attached the :as to the get path, attach to both if you need.

Comment: Another helpful trick, by convention if we leave out the "activites#clone" part rails will automatically assume action "clone" in controller "activities_controller"